# New to java and need some help making a call log system

Tags: java, authentication

I need to make my login button go to the next Class(page) of the system
atm i have add a few buttons i saw in videos and read about and really will like to make this work.

so I played around with a few commands but dont think i got it right.

Can you maybe tell me what I am doing extremely wrong?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class system {

    protected static final int Admin = 0;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField Usernameinput;
    private JTextField Passwordinput;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            public void run() {
                try {
                    system window = new system();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public system() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 534, 365);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String username;
                String password;

                System.out.println("Log in:");
                System.out.println("username: ");
                Scanner input = null;
                username = input.next();

                System.out.println("password: ");
                password = input.next();

                //users check = new users(username, password);
                if (Usernameinput.equals(Admin) && Passwordinput.equals(Admin)) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome");
                };

            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(29, 242, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

        JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
        btnReset.setBounds(144, 242, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnReset);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setBounds(397, 282, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnExit);

        Usernameinput = new JTextField();
        Usernameinput.setBounds(144, 74, 209, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Usernameinput);
        Usernameinput.setColumns(10);

        Passwordinput = new JTextField();
        Passwordinput.setColumns(10);
        Passwordinput.setBounds(144, 106, 209, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Passwordinput);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
        lblUsername.setBounds(73, 77, 55, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
        lblPassword.setBounds(73, 108, 55, 17);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setBounds(10, 211, 498, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        separator_1.setBounds(10, 57, 498, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separator_1);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to The System v 0.1");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(182, 5, 151, 41);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake in your `btnLogin.addActionListener`. You don't need the `input` here. Usually we need `Scanner` to read the input from the console.

But now as we have a UI we can get the user input from the specific `JTextField`s. In your case username from `Usernameinput` and password from `Passwordinput`.

```
username = Usernameinput.getText();
password = Passwordinput.getText();
```

---

Next the `if` statement in your `btnLogin.addActionListener` must check the text inside the `JTextFields`. As we have already obtained those and kept in the variables `username` and `password` you can use those.

And you can't use `String.equals` method with an `int`. `username.equals(Admin)` will always return `false` since the variable `Admin` is an `int`. So change,

```
if (username.equals("username") && password.equals("password")) {
    System.out.println("Welcome");
};
```

---

Finally you can remove unused `import` statements (optional).

```
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.JTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thank you for the help

But like now if i press Login it goes to a consol page where is says welcome but will like it to go to the next class??

Answer (score 0):

never mind found out how to add it

now i just need to make use of the second frame